Ros2 Humble colcon build error
I am learning ros2 and I am having problem with colcon build command. I am running ARM based Ubuntu 22.04 virtual machine on my Macbook. Here is the error that I am getting on my terminal after running colcon build command.
I used official ros2 humble webpage. i used Binary packages and installed Debian packages.
First, I enabled Ubuntu Universe repository.
sudo apt install software-properties-common
sudo add-apt-repository universe
sudo apt update && sudo apt install curl -y
sudo curl -sSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ros/rosdistro/master/ros.key -o /usr/share/keyrings/ros-archive-keyring.gpg
echo "deb [arch=$(dpkg --print-architecture) signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/ros-archive-keyring.gpg] http://packages.ros.org/ros2/ubuntu $(. /etc/os-release && echo $UBUNTU_CODENAME) main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros2.list > /dev/null

Then I updated my apt repositories and installed ros2 packages:
sudo apt install ros-humble-desktop
sudo apt install ros-humble-ros-base
sudo apt install ros-dev-tools

After this step I installed colcon and tried to build my first project file and get following error:
(base) parallels@ubuntu-linux-22-04-02-desktop:~/Workspaces/

udemy_ros2_ws$ colcon build
Starting >>> udemy_ros2_pkg
--- stderr: udemy_ros2_pkg                         
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/ros/humble/share/ament_cmake_core/cmake/core/package_xml_2_cmake.py", line 22, in <module>
    from catkin_pkg.package import parse_package_string
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'catkin_pkg'
CMake Error at /opt/ros/humble/share/ament_cmake_core/cmake/core/ament_package_xml.cmake:95 (message):
  execute_process(/home/parallels/miniconda3/bin/python3
  /opt/ros/humble/share/ament_cmake_core/cmake/core/package_xml_2_cmake.py
  /home/parallels/Workspaces/udemy_ros2_ws/src/udemy_ros2_pkg/package.xml
  /home/parallels/Workspaces/udemy_ros2_ws/build/udemy_ros2_pkg/ament_cmake_core/package.cmake)
  returned error code 1
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /opt/ros/humble/share/ament_cmake_core/cmake/core/ament_package_xml.cmake:49 (_ament_package_xml)
  /opt/ros/humble/share/ament_lint_auto/cmake/ament_lint_auto_find_test_dependencies.cmake:31 (ament_package_xml)
  CMakeLists.txt:23 (ament_lint_auto_find_test_dependencies)



Failed   <<< udemy_ros2_pkg [0.79s, exited with code 1]
                                
Summary: 0 packages finished [1.10s]
  1 package failed: udemy_ros2_pkg
  1 package had stderr output: udemy_ros2_pkg
(base) parallels@ubuntu-linux-22-04-02-desktop:~/Workspaces/udemy_ros2_ws$ 

Interestingly after running command, 'build' , 'install' and 'log' folders appeared in the workspace.
I also have miniconda installed on my computer.

Please edit your question to explain what you have installed and how you have setup your environment. This looks like you're missing a dependency, but how to resolve that depends on your setup.

You seem to have two accounts (1 and 2). It is considered bad form to earn rep by suggesting edits your own posts. Please read I accidentally created two accounts; how do I merge them?. Also, please take the [tour].
